# The vscode vim extension does not write real characters?

Tags: vim, visual-studio-code

I have customized the vim-extension in vscode, and for most modes, it executes commands correctly. However If I try to write actuall characters (which are thus no longer commands), it won't. Why is that?

Example:

```
"vim.insertModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [
        {
            "before": [
                "<leader>",
                "o"
            ],
            "after": [
                "<Esc>",
                "i",
                "Abcd"
            ]
        },
]
```

This should only write `Abcd`, because before that sequence is `i`, switching into insert mode. (So the `<Esc>` -> `i`, is redundant, it is here just as example). The vscode vim extension executes the `<Esc>` and also the `i` (becuase I know after that command I am back in insert mode), but will not print the `Abcd`. Why? Is the extension configured just to execute commands and not to actually print something? How to enable that?

Comment: maybe a stupid question. but have you tried removing the `"<Esc>", "i"` part from the mapping?

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo I did - the same result. But that was just as an example. Anyway in both cases Vscode-vim will *not* output it

Comment: hmm https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim#vscodevim-settings see the debug options there. it should allow for debugging mappings too. Unfortunately I can't really help you any further since I do not use vscode. I just had one idea of what the problem could be and your comment does not point in that direction

Comment: Can you clarify what is you're trying to achieve? It looks like

While in Insert Mode, `<leader>o` writes *Abcd* to the file at the current cursor location?

Comment: @dwrecked yes, it should. But it does not. I am trying to simply "print" (write `Abcd`, as an example, with shortcut), but with vim extension, it seems I cannot "print" like that

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you just need to split each character of the `"Abcd"` on to a separate line:

```
"vim.insertModeKeyBindingsNonRecursive": [
    {
        "before": [
            "<leader>",
            "o"
        ],
        "after": [
            "<Esc>",
            "i",
            "A",
            "b",
            "c",
            "d"
        ]
    },
]
```

Comment: neither that helped.

Comment: Hmm other than having mine set up as an explicit "\\" instead of <leader>, what's above is currently working fine for me. Unfortunately, I'm not sure what else could be contributing - sorry about that!

Comment: @milanHrabos One more question - are you seeing `<leader>o` inserted by your typing and then deleted? When this works for me, those characters are inserted, then deleted and replaced with the `Abcd`. If the original characters are not deleted, then that suggests that the command never fires.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim#viminsertmodekeybindingsnonrecursivenormalmodekeybindingsnonrecursivevisualmodekeybindingsnonrecursiveoperatorpendingmodekeybindingsnonrecursive) of the project, you are supposed to pass a single key character (single character for normal key and multiple characters for special keys such as arrow keys or escape keys).

Updating after value will solve the issue:

```
"after": [
    "<Esc>",
    "i",
    "A", "b", "c", "d"
]
```

You can take a look at the internals of the plugin to understand why it is not working with multiple characters passes in [here](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/blob/master/src/configuration/validators/remappingValidator.ts), specifically [NormalizeKey](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/blob/master/src/configuration/notation.ts#L45) function, which would wrap any string with multiple characters with <>.